# coldfusion IIF statement with parameters

Tags: coldfusion

I'm working on a coldfusion line trying to work out what this line means. I'm new to CF so excuse my
ignorance.

```
<CFSET is_box = IIF(_boxes[1].name EQ application.box,1,0)>
```

I presume _boxes is an array of objects and if the index 1 in that array is equal to application.box then what does 1, 0 mean.
Is it like a shorthand js statement where is does the below.

```
is_box = ( _boxes[1].name == application.box ) ? 1 : 0;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it like a shorthand js statement where is does the below.

yes it is, except the string comparison is case-insensitive.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7f4f.html

*edit:* You may, if you're using CF9 or above, refactor it into

```
<CFSET is_box = _boxes[1].name EQ application.box ? 1 : 0>
```

Comment: Actually, the ternary operator (? : ) only became available in CF9

Comment: if you want case sensitivity, you could also weap the java String method .equals(), which returns boolean

Comment: or use compare() if you want to stay in CFML